# rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[page Size]=10 giving signature error magento 2.4.5

Tags: magento2, error, api, rest-api, magento2.4.5

I am calling Magento rest API to load all products of a site.

```
https://store_url/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10
```

It gives the following error -

```
 "message": "The signature is invalid. Verify and try again."
```

I am calling it through a Laravel project.  I am not getting any errors while calling a single product or order GET API. I am only getting this error for the APIs that contain query parameters.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the API from another source of a project, like Laravel, you will definitely get this error as:

- The signature error occurs with either a malformed URL or rejected Access Token/Token Secret authorized by admin.

Did you try to run it on Postman?

So, first, you need to authorize: Try using a bearer token , set up HTTP client operation header "Content-Type = application/json" , "Authorization = Bearer

To generate a Token, follow this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

You can also go through this:
https://github.com/grayloon/magento-laravel-api

Comment: But  https://store_url/rest/V1/products/productSku  this API is working perfectly.

Comment: Then first try to Run in Postman, if everything works fine means there is an issue an Oath Authentication. Next the solution is to try to run the with token based.

Comment: In postman it is ok. But I have to go with OAuth.

Comment: Let's connect then to see this in detail please connect on Skype: jyotishina.rajwani

Answer (score 0):

In assumption this use for dev environment or published resource such as catalog, you can done it without authenticator, try this https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/config/services/magento-web-api.html?lang=en#web-api-security

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from this method in the codebase `\Magento\Framework\Oauth\Oauth::_validateSignature`

Seems that your generated `oauth_signature` value in your request headers does not match the `oauth_signature_method` you've defined in your request headers? A reminder that in Magento version 2.4, Magento only allows for `HMAC-SHA256` signatures.

If the above is not the issue, maybe your request is missing some data? Certainly seems to be an issue with authentication regardless. Would definitely be worth having a read of the Magento Oauth devdocs - linked below:

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth/#get-a-request-token

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve this? I'm having the exact same issue, can do `https://store_url/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/XXXXXX` but not `https://store_url/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=10`.

It's actually working on Postman but not on my integration.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/208468)